# How can you make a prefab that can expand to show its constituent objects?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am very new to Unity3d. I want to make an prefab that expands with a little right facing button to show other objects. I have tried giving the prefab children and then dragging it into the project window, but it didn't show the little right-facing arrow. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

To add components to a prefab, add it to the scene as you said you have, then drag your next object on top of the prefab in the Hierarchy window. Sometimes this places it relative to the prefab but does not actually child it, so simply drag the object now in your Hierarchy onto your prefab once more and it should fall in place as a child, you will know this worked if you now have an expand node next to your prefab.

Answer (score 1):

First, make your root game object that you will convert into a prefab.

In order to add objects which are children, right click on the root object and then make the children. You can also drag other gameobjects onto the root game object to make them children of the root game object.

Finally, drag your final prefab into window where all of your files are, and the resulting prefab will have children.

If you want to change the prefab after it is made, you have to change one object that results from your prefab and after changing it, click Apply in the top of the Inspector window to apply that change to all other objects resulting from the same prefab.